# meta tag placement for google verification

Tags: query-posts

Please tell me in simple terms starting from the dashboard of a 3.3.1 webpage how to get to the place where I put this meta tag google is requiring in order to verify my site.

If you start with on the main page--Please explain how to get there. My main page is just a post. then I have other pages.

I've placed this meta tag all over my pages and google has not been able verify from any of them.

Comment: This question is incomprehensible. What verification code? Google has a LOT of services.

Answer (score 1):

The `meta` tag Google is searching for has to be put into the `head` section of your HTML. You cannot change this section in a post editor. If you don’t want to edit your theme files:

1. Install the plugin [Magic Widgets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-widgets/) and activate it (*Plugins/Add new*).
2. Got to *Design/Widgets* and drag the Widget *Unfiltered Text* into the header box.
3. Copy the `meta` element into the box and click *Save*. Done.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

the meta verification code should be in the `<head>` section, which you usually find in header.php of the used theme.

***dashboard - appearance - editor*** -

select *header.php* from the list on the right;

add the meta verification code in its own line before `</head>`;

click **update file**

Comment: This will be overwritten after the next theme update.

Comment: @toscho - thanks, I am aware of that possibility - just too lazy to write this into my answer.